# Excel vba - How to refer to workbook builtin document properties in excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am building a macro workbook in which `ctl+D` is deactivated.
**Now, the issue is** - When another workbook is opened when this macro workbook is still open, `ctl+D` is getting disabled in the other workbook as well, as this is an application level setting. I want to restrict disabling `ctl+D` only in the macro workbook.

For this, I can add a condition in the code which checks for the workbook name before disabling `ctl+D`. But, there is 90% chance that users would change the name of the workbook after saving to their desktop.

Is there a way I can use **Workbook builtin properties** instead of workbook name in code? Please advise.

Thank you!

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.builtindocumentproperties.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

**Example (Pseudo code):**

```
if ThisWorkbook.Title = 'TEST' Then
    Application.OnKey "^d", ""
end if
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use workbook events to detect when the workbook is activated or not.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    Application.OnKey "^d", ""
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    Application.OnKey "^d"
End Sub
```

Put this in the ThisWorkbook module. You might also want to add the Ctrl+d deactivation line to a Workbook_Open event.